# INDEX MATCH multiple criteria with multiple results - sum results

Tags: indexing, sum, boolean, match

I have created a successful INDEX MATCH statement using Boolean logic that returns the correct value. Unfortunately it returns only the first value it finds but I want it to find all of the correct values in column B and sum them together. Any way to add this component into the formula below?

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Bell ISC WWTB'!$B$2:$B$200,MATCH(1,(((B5='Bell ISC WWTB'!$A$2:$A$200))*($R$2='Bell ISC WWTB'!$F$2:$F$200)*($S$6='Bell ISC WWTB'!$H$2:$H$200)*($N$2>='Bell ISC WWTB'!$C$2:$C$200)*($O$2<='Bell ISC WWTB'!$D$2:$D$200)),0)),"0")}
```

Comment: Why doesn't SUMIFS work?

Comment: How would you write that with the criteria above?

Comment: If I didn't know how SUMIFS worked, I would go and read about it on support.office.com then try to type in a formula into my worksheet. If it didn't work, I would come back here and edit my question to include my own effort with SUMIFS and describe why it is not working, including any error codes that occurred.